# Sharing a HttpSession object between different EAR's

Tags: java, httpsession

Is it possible to share an HttpSession object between different EAR's when they're running on the server?  For example, I have a session object named ses, and I create it in the LogOn servlet for my web app with a url of http://webserver:9080/LANDRECORDS/LogOn.  But when I redirect to another EAR running on the server (for example http://webserver:9080/MARRIAGE/InqMRMenu) ses no longer exists.  I'm trying to make use of existing code in other systems rather than copy it all into one new project.

Comment: Just [set the cookie path to /](http://orebmann.blogspot.com/2013/03/http-session-id-reuse-in-websphere.html) if you are using cookies. Of course, on both application.

Comment: I will give that a shot.  Thank you!